# DBMS_DATAPUMP API export/import tables from different schemas

Tags: oracle, plsql, datapump

I would like to export import tables from multiple schemas with DBMS_DATAPUMP API.
EG user1.table1 user2.table2 user3.table3
I give in a parameter the tables like a list with comma separated. 'user1.table1,user2.table2,user3.table3'
After that I store in a table the list of tables.
Then I read in a cursor the content of the table and go through in the cursor with a LOOP and give the schemas and table names one by one.

```
LOOP
 dbms_datapump.metadata_filter(handle => h1, name => 'NAME_EXPR', value => 'IN('table1'));
 dbms_datapump.metadata_filter(handle => h1, name => 'SCHEMA_LIST', value => 'IN('user1'));
END LOOP.
```

The first table is successfully added to the dbms_datapump job, but the second table exit with error.

> ORA-39071: Value of SCHEMA_LIST is badly formed.
> ORA-00936: missing exprension

I tired to find solutions how to exp/imp with DBMS_DATAPUMP API tables from different schemas but I have found any examples. The examples whih I found only shows if you are exp/imp from one schema.
Thanks in advance

Comment: What are you actually executing? The code you posted is not syntactically correct. Just look at the `'` and `)` characters. An MCV example starting with user creation should not take long to create nor should it take up much vertical space in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

--For Table mode, only a single `SCHEMA_EXPR` filter is supported. If specified, it must only specify a single schema (for example, `'IN (''SCOTT'')'`).

```
DBMS_DATAPUMP.METADATA_FILTER(handle, 'SCHEMA_EXPR', 'IN('||vschemas||')');
```

--you can enter more than one table name, but no more than 4000 characters (literal limit), including special characters.

```
DBMS_DATAPUMP.METADATA_FILTER(handle, 'NAME_EXPR', 'IN('||vtables||')', 'TABLE');
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax using a variable for the SCHEMA_EXPR is not valid. **"'SCHEMA_EXPR', 'IN('||vschemas||')');"**